# BizTalk 2010 mapping to OAGIS 10.1 BOD ProcessSalesOrder Map Performance Issue

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

Background: we needed a more mature canonical message format for our ESB solutions than our home grown canonical that is outdated. I researched a bit and found OAGIS looked very promising and I liked the document model. I downloaded version 10.1 and picked out the BOD's I would first implement. I am working specifically with ProcessSalesOrder in BizTalk 2010 mapping a fairly simple web service schema to the ProcessSalesOrder BOD. I got the map where I think I like it but it creates a lot of bloated tags I don't need or want and map execution (at least in my virtual server workstation environment) takes forever to execute. As the map attached to the WCF call in BizTalk Receive location it will time out.

[OAGIS 10.1 Download page](http://www.oagi.org/dnn2/DownloadsandResources/OAGIS101PublicDownloadPage.aspx)

Question is has anyone tried to optimize the schemas for OAGIS 10.1?

I can only find BizTalk references with much older versions where the schema was broken into nouns and components - this isn't the case for 10.1 there is only one LARGE schema for ProcessSalesOrder. I have set my root reference properly.

Can the BOD be edited to remove sections that aren't being used without a ton of dev time?

Any thoughts or suggestions are desperately needed before I scratch the project and go to modifying our crappy canonical for expediency sake.

Comment: Can you give the XSL of the map?

Comment: actual code would be confidential.  It seems to execute faster in server on the receive location - just takes forever while manually testing map in Visual Studio - so much so that I became concerned if it would be viable in solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you leave unneeded fields unmapped. the map should excute pretty fast. To test just the map performance, can you try to do test map and see how it performs?
Another option can be stripping of unwanted data in Recieve pipeline before it hits the map

Comment: I am just using test map - the input schema is lean.  No unneeded data.  I haven't tried it yet on my receive location.

Comment: Is there specific issue you are facing that we can help with? But yes, in virtual environment Mapper Designer Interface is very slow and takes time to load for even simple smaller maps. however, once compiled the performance would be better.

Comment: Input format is already pretty slim.  It did compile and perform fairly well.  I was impressed given the huge lag time when testing interactively in VS.  So I guess there is no real problem - just a learning curve in dealing with the bit of bloat the schema creates but overall I think it is a much better choice as our canonical.